# Using dependency injection to lazy load domain model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, repository-pattern

I am currently using the repository pattern where I have my data models behind a repository that return my domain models. I am using dependency injection to do all of this.

My problem is, let's say I have a domain model `Student` which I get from my `StudentRepository`. `Student` may have properties on it that I use in some places, but not others, for example, `Courses`:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Student(int id, string name, IEnumerable courses = null)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        _courses = courses;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Course> _courses;
    
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses()
    {
        if(_courses == null)
        {
            // I need a good way to load the CourseRepository
            _courses = CourseRepository.GetCoursesByStudentID(ID);
        }

        return _courses;
    }
}
```

Therefore, I want this type of lazy loading set up but I do not know how I can do it elegantly, and is difficult for me to understand how I can load the implementation of the `CourseRepository` (or `ICourseRepository` using DI), where my repository looks like:

```
public class CourseRepository : ICourseRepository
{
    private DbContext _db;
    
    public CourseRepository(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DomainModels.Course> GetCoursesByStudentID(int studentID)
    {
        return CourseFactory.Build(_db.Courses.Where(c=>c.StudentID == studentID));
    }
}
```

This is not critical for an answer, but it would help if the solution were relative to Ninject since that is my current DI container.

Comment: Do you have a student repository as well?